# How is the bar formed in a Barred-Spiral galaxy?

Tags: galaxy, formation, spiral-arms

How does the bar in a barred spiral galaxy form? What prevents it from being spirals all the way down like water spiralling down a plughole?

Comment: For one, spirals in a spiral galaxy are not the same as spirals in draining water. You can't expect the same behavior because the same physics is not governing both concepts.

Answer (score 4):

"Galactic bars develop when stellar orbits in a spiral galaxy become unstable and deviate from a circular path. The tiny elongations
in the stars’ orbits grow and get locked into place, forming a bar. The bar becomes even more pronounced as it collects more and
more stars in elliptical orbits. Eventually, a high fraction of the stars in the galaxy’s inner region join the bar. This process has been
demonstrated repeatedly with computer-based simulations."

Source:
http://hubblesite.org/hubble_discoveries/science_year_in_review/pdf/2008/barred_spiral_galaxies_and_galactic_evolution.pdf

Comment: Please provide some more detail than a single quote.

Comment: Are you sure this is up-to-date? It has been known since the 70's that stars in a galaxy have neither purely circular nor purely elliptical orbits.

Comment: found a couple of physics sims here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rcQiLAktC-M and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lSymkkrbYZI